# I have a problem with comparing data in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of stock data, but i want to compare the data using greater than or less than signs. I want to be able to compare the data like I would normally be able to with normal integers / floats.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


money = 0
def runfunction():
  i = 0
  go = True
  while go == True:
    #try:
      bought = False
      if googl_macd["macd"][i] >= 4 & bought != True:
        print("here")
        #do strategy
        if googl_macd["macd"][i] > googl_macd["signal"] & googl_macd["hist"] > 2.5:
          print("here")
          #alpacaorder("GOOGL", BUY)
          print("Bought at", googl["close"])
          bought = True
          boughtprice = googl_macd["macd"]

      elif googl_macd["macd"] >= 4 and googl_macd["macd"] < googl_macd["signal"] & bought == True:
        #alpacaorder("GOOGL", SELL)
        print("Sold at", googl["close"])
        sellprice = googl_macd["macd"]
        money += sellprice - boughtprice
      i += 1
    #except Exception as e:
      #print(e)
      #go = False
      
runfunction()
print(money)
```

This is some of the Pandas data i am using

```
         macd    signal      hist
2020-01-02  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2020-01-03 -0.571168 -0.114234 -0.456934
2020-01-06  1.882773  0.285168  1.597606
2020-01-07  3.568536  0.941841  2.626695
2020-01-08  5.640760  1.881625  3.759135
```

And this is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zackz\Desktop\Zack-Emil.py", line 161, in <module>
    runfunction()
  File "c:\Users\zackz\Desktop\Zack-Emil.py", line 144, in runfunction
    if googl_macd["macd"][i] > googl_macd["signal"]: #& googl_macd["hist"] > 2.5:
  File "C:\Users\zackz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried to compare the different columns in the pandas data frame.

Sorry if this question has already been answered, i could not find anything specific to the problem that i had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
if googl_macd["macd"][i] > googl_macd["signal"] & googl_macd["hist"] > 2.5:
```

is comparing a single value from column "macd" to a whole column "signal". Try changing this to

```
if googl_macd["macd"][i] > googl_macd["signal"][i] & googl_macd["hist"][i] > 2.5:
```